# Launching Rattle

Tags: r, rattle

I have tried launching rattle in my system, it failed every time. I am using a Mac, system details are given below:

- macOS Big Sur
- 11.4 version
- Intel core i5 processor

Why am I receiving the same error?

[image]

Comment: is GTK+ installed and on path environment variable? This is what traceback suggests to check. Update your question with this info

Comment: cannot install gtk+ also. Path environment is set to global

Comment: are you following instructions here? https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-mac.html there is some instruction about installing gtk+ and setting PATH